# Antlr, get last line from token

Tags: line, antlr, token

I have a token definition that can contain multiple lines (something like multi line comments).

I can use the .line attribute to get the line where the token starts, but I need to
know where the token end.

Is it possible to get the last line of the token?

Comment: It is possible to change the line of a token to the line it ends on. But do you want both the start- and end-line? If you want them both, when do you want to access this information (inside a parser rule, or inside the lexer rule of the multi-line-comment token)?

Comment: Hi, I only need the end-line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the line number of a token by placing the (Java) code-block `{$line=getLine();}` at the **end** of the rule.

So, for multi-line comments, that would look like this:

```
COMMENT
  :  '/*' .* '*/' {$line=getLine();}
  ;
```

causing the method `getLine()` of the token `COMMENT` to return the line number the sub-string `"*/"` occurred on.