# Return the line number of the last character for current token

Tags: antlr4

Is there a way in ANTLR 4 to be able to return the line number of the the last character for the current token ?

I referred [Antlr, get last line from token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903021/antlr-get-last-line-from-token) but that would be specific to a rule. I wanted something more generic but couldn't find what would suit me in the ANTLR API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no direct way to get this information. However, if you don't have any `-> skip` commands in your lexer you can derive it from the following token.

Suppose token `b` follows token `a`. If `b.getCharPositionInLine()==0`, the last character of `a` is on line `b.getLine()-1`. Otherwise, the last character of `a` is on line `b.getLine()`.

Comment: Yes great but my grammar does have -> skip commands. Perhaps I could use the HIDDEN channel instead of the skip commands and that would allow me to work on the lines you have mentioned ?

Comment: Correct. Since you do need information from those tokens, you should use `-> channel(HIDDEN)` to hide them from the parser rules but still leave them in the stream where you can check their locations.