# Token text information

Tags: antlr4

I'm trying to get information about the position of the token text: begining/ending lines and columns.

Well, using getCharPositionInLine() and getLine() from Token API I can get some of the things I need. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487718/return-the-line-number-of-the-last-character-for-current-token) helped me about getting ending info. But, what about the last token in the token stream? How can I get the last column and the last line for the last token?

(maybe counting newlines in the text, but I don't like)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last token in the token stream is the `EOF` token, which has length 0. The line and column of that token is the ending line and column of the last "real" token in the stream.

Comment: I guessed something like that. Thank you!